# ggplot2 & stat_ellipse: Draw ellipses around multiple groups of points

Tags: r, ggplot2, ellipse

This might be a simple one, but I'm trying to draw ellipses around my treatments on my PCoA plot.

My data frame (sc) is:

```
             MDS1        MDS2 Treatment
X1xF1 -0.19736183 -0.24299825   1xFlood
X1xF2 -0.17409568 -0.29727596   1xFlood
X1xF3 -0.15272444 -0.28553837   1xFlood
S1    -0.06643271  0.47049959     Start
S2    -0.15143350  0.31152966     Start
S3    -0.26156297  0.12296849     Start
X3xF1  0.29840827  0.04581617  3xFloods
X3xF2  0.50503749 -0.07011503  3xFloods
X3xF3  0.20016537 -0.05488630  3xFloods
```

and my code is:

```
ggplot(data=sc,(aes(x=MDS1,y=MDS2,colour = Treatment)))+geom_point(size=3)+
  ggtitle("PCoA of samples at 'class' level(method='Bray')\n",sep=''))+
  theme_bw()+guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=3)))+
  stat_ellipse()
```

It plots the PCoA okay up until stat_ellipse(). I've tried it with various parameters and at best I can get one ellipse for the whole plot (although I can't seem to reproduce that now).

What I'm after is three CI ellipses for the three treatments, coloured the same as the treatments. Any help would be very appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Minimal reproducible example. That's kinda convoluted code when you're trying to focus on the problem of how to draw an ellipse.

Comment: Good point, thanks. I've removed the junk creating the data frame and just left the ggplot2 code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no `stat_ellipse(...)` in the `ggplot` package, so you must have retreived it from somewhere else. Care to share?? There are at least two versions that I am aware of, [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hadley/ggplot2/master/R/stat-ellipse.R), and [here](https://raw.github.com/low-decarie/FAAV/master/r/stat-ellipse.R). Neither of these seem to work with your dataset, which is odd because both have worked with other datasets.

I finally fell back on the option of generating the ellipses externally to `ggplot`, which is not that difficult really.

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ellipse)
centroids <- aggregate(cbind(MDS1,MDS2)~Treatment,sc,mean)
conf.rgn  <- do.call(rbind,lapply(unique(sc$Treatment),function(t)
  data.frame(Treatment=as.character(t),
             ellipse(cov(sc[sc$Treatment==t,1:2]),
                     centre=as.matrix(centroids[t,2:3]),
                     level=0.95),
             stringsAsFactors=FALSE)))

ggplot(data=sc,(aes(x=MDS1,y=MDS2,colour = Treatment)))+
  geom_point(size=3)+
  geom_path(data=conf.rgn)+
  ggtitle(paste("PCoA of samples at 'class' level(method='Bray')\n",sep=''))+
  theme_bw()+
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=3)))
```

Comment: The main issue is that stat_ellipse() is a wrapper function for car::ellipse() and geom_path(), and its default parameters trip up when there are a limited number of data pints.

Comment: Thanks jlhoward. stat_ellipse() is from devtools, sorry I forgot to mention it. I've tried using your code, but the ellipses aren't appearing, it just generates the normal plot, and I can't figure out why...

Comment: Try restarting R, then copy/paste the code exactly.

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately. When I type conf.rgn after running your function, I get a 300 x 3 data frame with col 1 as treatment (100 x each treatment), and col2 & 3 as MDS1 & MDS2. These final two columns are 'NA', so I think that's where the problem lies.

Comment: Hard to tell what's going on here. Do you get any error messages or warnings? Does your code to produce `sc` load any packages? If you load the `car` package, or if you load a package that requires `car`, that will mask the `ellipse(...)` function. But this should result in error messages.

Comment: I've got it working! I had as.character(sc$Treatment) when I was setting my factors, and removing that solved it. Now I just need to reorder the legend and change the legend symbols, and I'm sorted. Thanks for your help!