# Draw ellipse in PCA plot with 3 data points in each group

Tags: r, ggplot2, pca, ellipse, stat

I am using RNA transcriptome data "test.csv" to make PCA plot and draw an ellipse around each group with only three biological replicate data points.

[test.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8Deo.png)

Script

```
data <- read.csv("test.csv")
pca <- ggplot(data=data, aes(x = PCA.1, y = PCA.2)) +
  geom_point(data=data, aes(shape=Treatment, color=sampleID), size=5, stroke = 1.5) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(1, 2, 18, 20))+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#32CD32", "#008000", "#FF00FF", "#1E90FF", "#0000FF", "#FFD700", "#FF8C00", "#CD6600"))+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.key.size = unit(1.2, "cm"), legend.text = element_text(size = 25), text = element_text(size = 30))+
  stat_ellipse()
pca
```

This gives me [PCA Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7v4z.png) with a single ellipse.

Also, I tried to follow some solutions from **stack overflow** such as [solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24270667/20980634) but they give some kind of error.
How can I draw separate ellipses around each group?
Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you explicitly need to set `stat_ellipse(aes(group = ...))`.

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput` instead of images so we can reproduce your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't be allow to draw ellipse with only 3 points with `stat_ellipse`, a solution could be to use `geom_mark_ellipse` from `ggforce` package :

```
pca <- ggplot(data=data, aes(x = PCA.1, y = PCA.2)) +
  geom_point(data=data, aes(shape=Treatment, color=sampleID), size=5, stroke = 1.5) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(1, 2, 18, 20))+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#32CD32", "#008000", "#FF00FF", "#1E90FF", "#0000FF", "#FFD700", "#FF8C00", "#CD6600"))+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.key.size = unit(1.2, "cm"), legend.text = element_text(size = 25), text = element_text(size = 30))+
  ggforce::geom_mark_ellipse(aes(fill = sampleID,
                                 color = sampleID))
pca
```